# Can I reproject _id as id in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to send back id to the client instead of _id.  I would like to do this on the mongo side if possible.  Is there a way with the find statement to repoject the names of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregation framework allows you to rename fields, but a normal `find` does not. You'll need to do the fixup in your client code.

Many drivers (and frameworks) can do this automatically on the client side automatically (so, it's not happening on the Database). Depending on the programming language you're using, this is probably the most effective option.

Comment: Bummer, hopefully this is a future enhancement.  Re-projecting in aggregation works great would be nice to be able to do that sort of thing DB side, I.E. select field1 as something_else

Comment: I don't mind much as many drivers already do it ... that way the work is distributed and frees the DB from doing "busy-work".